# Azure Backup job fails because a backup or restore operation is currently running

Tags: azure, azureportal

Using *Azure Backup* the scheduled daily job fails every once in a while and a notification is sent:

> **Backup failure alert has been activated**
>
> - Severity : Critical
> - Alert : Backup failure
> - Description : The operation attempted cannot be performed at this time because a backup or restore operation is currently running.
> - Recommended action(s) : Wait until the operation finishes or cancel the currently running operation, and then try again.

It seems two jobs are started at the same time. Why?

Also, where can I see the scheduled jobs to confirm that only one daily job is scheduled? For some reason I can't seem to find this information either in the *Azure Portal* nor the *Microsoft Azure Backup* client. Am I missing something?

Comment: what does the error log says

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/696889/microsoft-azure-backup-where-are-the-logs

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thanks for the pointer to the logs. In CloudBackup events there is an "Error: The backup operation has completed with errors." with `<DetailedErrorCode>2147467259</DetailedErrorCode>`